# How to bind load event for img

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I know `$('img').load(function(){})` can work. However, I want the `img dom` those haven't been created at first can also `trigger the event`. I wonder why the below doesn't work.

```
$(window.document).on('load', 'img', function(){
    console.log('load', this);
})
```

Comment: You can't because [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) does not bubble, so it doesn't support delegated handlers

Comment: Thanks. I get the right way. It doesn't because bubble but capture model.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't support capture. So I had to use js's addEventListener.

```
document.body.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function(event){
        var tgt = event.target;
        if( tgt.tagName == 'IMG'){
            console.log('load', tgt.src);
        }
    },
    true
)
```